# Cauchy's Theorem by Differential Geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, complex-geometry

Is there a prove of Cauchy's theorem footing on the topology of the complex plane (homotopy, differential forms, etc.)?

More specific consider a differentiable Banach space valued complex function. Prove that the integral along every closed differentiable curve vanishes:
$$\oint\omega=0\text{ for all }\omega\in\Omega(\mathbb{C})$$

*(Though it is precisely what analysis is about I just don't like the usual proof by shrinking triangles since it is kind of technical so I hope there might be one showing why complex differentiable is so much more than just its real analogue.)*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a holomorphic function: $f:A\to\mathbb{C}$

Consider the real manifold: $M:=D\subseteq A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^2:\quad\partial D=S$
and the real one forms: $\omega:=udx-vdy,\tilde{\omega}:=ydx+xdy:\quad u=\mathrm{Re}f,v=\mathrm{Im}f$

Then we have:
$$f\text{ holomorphic}\Rightarrow u,v\text{ C-R}\Rightarrow\omega,\tilde{\omega}\text{ closed}\Rightarrow\int_S\omega,\tilde{\omega}=0\Rightarrow\oint\omega,\tilde{\omega}=0\Rightarrow\oint f=0$$

...where the domain is simply connected so that any path is homotopic to eachother...
...and the manifold is chosen compact so that Stoke's theorem is applicable...
...and simply connected so its boundary is a closed curve.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, if we're in the smooth category, holomorphicity of $f$ is equivalent to the fact that the $1$-form $\omega = f(z)\,dz$ is closed. And Cauchy's Theorem is just Green/Stokes's Theorem. Homotopy-invariance is just the general topological fact that if $f$ and $g$ are homotopic maps $S^1\to D$ (for some domain $D\subset\Bbb C$), then $\int_{S^1} f^*\omega = \int_{S^1} g^*\omega$ for any closed $1$-form $\omega$.

**EDIT**: The best way to see my first statement is to do the exercise of turning 
$$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$
into
$$df = \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz + \frac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}d\bar z$$
by using $dz = dx+i\,dy$, $d\bar z = dx - i\,dy$. You'll easily check that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are equivalent to $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z} = 0$. Then, if we have the $1$-form $\omega = f(z)\,dz$, we see that $d\omega = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial\bar z}d\bar z\wedge dz = 0$ if and only if $f$ is holomorphic.

Comment: But why is holomorphicity equivalent to being closed?

Comment: Moreover isn't Stoke's theorem stating: $\int_\mathbb{C}\mathrm{d}\omega=\int_{\partial\\mathrm{C}=\varnothing}\omega$

Comment: Yes but that only shows that $f\text{ differentiable}$ not that $f\mathrm{d}z=\mathrm{d}g$ for some $g\in\mathcal{C}^\infty(\mathbb{C})$

Comment: I had some typos in my earlier comment. Stokes's Theorem tells us that for any compact, oriented manifold $M$ with boundary, $\int_M d\omega = \int_{\partial M} \omega$, and this holds for any bounded region $M=R\subset\Bbb C$, so $\int_R d\omega = \int_{\partial R} \omega = \int_C \omega$, if $C=\partial R$. As for your other comment, you're confusing *closed* and *exact*. But, yes, in a simply connected region, closed=exact, so a holomorphic function does have a primitive.

Comment: I'm confused: once you consider the complex plane as a 1-dimensional complex manifold ones as a two dimensional real manifold? If so how how can you turn a complex form into a real form if its coefficient functions are not necessarily real?

Comment: For example the last expression should read: $\mathrm{d}\omega=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\mathrm{d}z\wedge \mathrm{d}z=0\text{ trivially}$

Comment: However if you write this as real form then clearly your last statement holds but it is not even well defined, e.g.: $\mathrm{d}x+\mathrm{i}\mathrm{d}y\text{ ???}$

Comment: This is all part of complex manifold theory. We are working with the complexified cotangent bundle. The simplest way to say this is that we're thinking of $\Bbb C$ as a $2$-dimensional real manifold along with *complex-valued* $1$-forms. As far as your last comment is concerned, $df = \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial z}dz$ if and only if $f$ is holomorphic. Try it out with $\omega = \bar z\,dz$.

Comment: Yes but complex valued 1-forms over real manifolds simply make no sense...

Comment: You're wrong. You can study complex-valued functions on real manifolds. More generally, we study sections of (real or complex) vector bundles, which correspond to twisted (real or complex) functions on the manifold.

Comment: Hmm ok well this might be necessary anyway as soon as one wants to show Cauchy's theorem on complex Banach spaces...

Comment: But what about all the theorems like Stoke's do they still apply?